# Как при помощи ajax проверить существует ли proverka.html?

Tags: ajax, html, json, php, javascript

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "http://url/r/proverka.html?r="+u,
                success:    файл есть;
                        error:файла нет;
                    }
            }
            );
```

Comment: jsonp это необычный ajax,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Выдержка из документации:](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

```
$.ajax({
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            alert( "page not found" );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Все равно не работает
alert не работает...
>GET http://webandgames.ru/sda.html?callback=jQuery1111015645090653561056_1406560927066&_=1406560927067 404 (Not Found) 


    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        </head>
    <body>
    
    <script>
    $.ajax({
     url: "http://webandgames.ru/sda.html",
     dataType:'jsonp',
        statusCode: {
            404: function() {
                alert( "page not found" );
            }
     }
    });
    
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: [всё работает](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/4mYtU/)